# How to add the custom rule in checkstyle.xml for Codacy in android studio?

Tags: android, codacy

I want to add custom rules in checkstyle so that I can view them in codacy Dashboard. But it is not showing in codacy dashboard either and giving error in android studio also, please find details below. 
I have written a custom class which extends the Check class but not able to add the class in checkstyle.xml. It is showing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XflME.png)error not able to instantiate the class.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
"-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.2//EN"
"http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_2.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
<module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile" />
<module name="FileLength" />
<module name="FileTabCharacter" />
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="packageName.MethodCallWithoutObjectCreation" />
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle" />
    <module name="UpperEll" />
    <module name="Indentation">
        <property name="caseIndent" value="4" />
    </module>
</module>
```

The above mentioned module can be found below as a java class MethodCallWithoutObjectCreation.java

```
public class MethodCallWithoutObjectCreation extends Check {

    @Override
    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
            return new int[]{TokenTypes.METHOD_DEF};
    }

    /**
     * @see com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.Check#visitToken(com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST)
     */
    @Override
    public void visitToken(DetailAST aast) {
            super.visitToken(aast);
            DetailAST slist = aast.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.SLIST);
            List<DetailAST> variables = DetailASTUtil.getDetailASTsForTypeInBranch(
                    slist, TokenTypes.VARIABLE_DEF);
            List<DetailAST> uninitializedVars = new ArrayList<DetailAST>();
            for (DetailAST variable : variables) {
                    boolean initialized = JavaClassUtil
                            .isVariableInitialized(variable);
                    if (!initialized)
                            uninitializedVars.add(variable);
            }

            for (DetailAST uninitializedVar : uninitializedVars) {
                    String uninitializedVarName = uninitializedVar.findFirstToken(
                            TokenTypes.IDENT).getText();
                    List<DetailAST> siblingsBelow = DetailASTUtil
                            .getAllSiblingsBelow(uninitializedVar);
                    List<FullIdentComparable> methodCallsFullIdents = new ArrayList<FullIdentComparable>();
                    List<FullIdentComparable> assignmentFullIdents = new ArrayList<FullIdentComparable>();
                    for (DetailAST siblingBelow : siblingsBelow) {
                            getListOfMethodCallsOnVariable(uninitializedVarName,
                                    siblingBelow, methodCallsFullIdents);
                            getListOfVariableAssignment(uninitializedVarName, siblingBelow,
                                    assignmentFullIdents);
                    }
                    Collections.sort(methodCallsFullIdents);
                    Collections.sort(assignmentFullIdents);
                    FullIdentComparable assignFullIdent = null;
                    if (assignmentFullIdents.size() > 0) {
                            assignFullIdent = assignmentFullIdents.get(0);
                    }

                    FullIdentComparable methodCallFullIdent = null;
                    if (methodCallsFullIdents.size() > 0)
                            methodCallFullIdent = methodCallsFullIdents.get(0);
                    if (methodCallFullIdent != null
                            && (methodCallFullIdent.compareTo(assignFullIdent) < 0))
                            log(uninitializedVar, "Method called without checking null "
                                    + methodCallFullIdent.getFullIdent().getText());
            }
    }

    private void getListOfMethodCallsOnVariable(String uninitializedVarName,
                                                DetailAST siblingBelow,
                                                List<FullIdentComparable> methodCallsFullIdents) {
            List<DetailAST> dotsInBranch = DetailASTUtil
                    .getDetailASTsForTypeInBranch(siblingBelow, TokenTypes.DOT);
            for (DetailAST dotInBranch : dotsInBranch) {
                    List<DetailAST> dotChildren = DetailASTUtil
                            .getDetailASTsForTypeInChildren(dotInBranch,
                                    TokenTypes.IDENT);
                    if (dotChildren != null) {
                            DetailAST dotChild = dotChildren.get(0);
                            if (dotChild.getText().equals(uninitializedVarName)) {
                                    FullIdent fullIdent = FullIdent
                                            .createFullIdent(dotInBranch);
                                    methodCallsFullIdents
                                            .add(new FullIdentComparable(fullIdent));
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    private void getListOfVariableAssignment(String uninitializedVarName,
                                             DetailAST siblingBelow,
                                             List<FullIdentComparable> assignmentFullIdents) {
            List<DetailAST> assignmentsInBranch = DetailASTUtil
                    .getDetailASTsForTypeInBranch(siblingBelow, TokenTypes.ASSIGN);
            for (DetailAST assignInBranch : assignmentsInBranch) {
                    DetailAST ident = assignInBranch.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.IDENT);
                    if (ident != null) {
                            if (ident.getText().equals(uninitializedVarName)) {
                                    FullIdent fullIdent = FullIdent
                                            .createFullIdent(assignInBranch);
                                    assignmentFullIdents
                                            .add(new FullIdentComparable(fullIdent));
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, visit the help center, and read up on asking good questions. After doing some research and searching for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: codacy doesn't support custom rules if I recall correctly

Answer (score 1):

For now Codacy doesn't support custom rules for xml and java using checkstyle, though you can customize their predefined rules which are listed inside code patterns section on Codacy Dashboard